# Gradient of distance function corresponding Riemmanian metric

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M, g)$ be a compact manifold with strictly convex boundary. The distance function $d_{g}: M \times M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$
d_{g}(x, y)=\inf _{\gamma \in \Lambda_{x, y}} \ell_{g}(\gamma)
$$
where $\Lambda_{x, y}$ denotes the set of smooth curves $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow M$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma(1)=y$ and
$$
\ell_{g}(\gamma):=\int_{0}^{1}|\dot{\gamma}(t)|_{g} d t
$$

Following theorem computes gradient of distance function:

Theorem:  Let $(M, g)$ be a simple manifold. Given $x \in M$, let $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(y)=d_{g}(x, y)$. For any $y \in M$ with $y \neq x$, let $\eta_{x, y}$ be the unique unit speed geodesic connecting $x$ to $y$ and let $\ell_{x, y}>0$ be such that $\eta_{x, y}\left(\ell_{x, y}\right)=y$. Then
$$
\nabla f(y)=\dot{\eta}_{x, y}\left(\ell_{x, y}\right)
$$

Proof:  On a simple manifold, the exponential map
$$
\exp _{x}: D_{x} \rightarrow M
$$
is a diffeomorphism. Recall also that for any pair of points in $M$ there is a unique geodesic between them, and this geodesic minimizes length. Thus when $t v \in D_{x}$ and $|v|_{g}=1$, one has
$$
f\left(\exp _{x}(t v)\right)=d_{g}\left(x, \exp _{x}(t v)\right)=t
$$
If $y=\exp _{x}(t v)$, it follows that
$$
\left.d f\right|_{y}\left(\dot{\gamma}_{x, v}(t)\right)=\frac{d}{d t} f\left(\gamma_{x, v}(t)\right)=\frac{d}{d t} f\left(\exp _{x}(t v)\right)=\frac{d}{d t}(t)=1
$$

**Till this, I understood. With this we now have gradient of function corresponding $\dot{\gamma}_{x, v}(t)$. But I do not understand the following.**

Moreover, if $\beta:(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \rightarrow S_{x} M$ is a smooth curve with $\beta(0)=v$, then
$$
\left.d f\right|_{y}\left(\left.d \exp _{x}\right|_{t v}(t \dot{\beta}(0))\right)=\left.\frac{d}{d s} f\left(\exp _{x}(t \beta(s))\right)\right|_{s=0}=\left.\frac{d}{d s}(t)\right|_{s=0}=0
$$
Any vector $w \perp v$ arises as $\dot{\beta}(0)$ for some $\beta .$ Since $\left.d \exp _{x}\right|_{t v}$ is invertible, it maps $\{v\}^{\perp}$ onto $\left\{\dot{\gamma}_{x, v}(t)\right\}^{\perp}$ by the Gauss lemma . It follows that $\left.d f\right|_{y}(\tilde{w})=0$ whenever $\tilde{w} \perp \dot{\gamma}_{x, v}(t) .$ Thus $\nabla f(y)=\dot{\gamma}_{x, v}(t)=\dot{\eta}_{x, y}\left(\ell_{x, y}\right)$.

**I am guessing that author is trying to find a gradient corresponding to the perpendicular vector field of $\dot{\gamma}_{x, v}(t)$. But I do not understand how he is doing.**

Would you please help me to understand that paragraph? Any help or hint will be highly appreciated.