# Do geodesics locally follow the gradient of the distance function?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, geodesic, gradient-descent

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and consider the metric

$$d(p,q) = \inf \{ l(\gamma) | \gamma: [0,1] \to M \text{ piecewise smooth with } \gamma(0) = p, \gamma (1) = q \}$$
where $l(\gamma)$ is the length of a curve.

In Eucliden space $\mathbb{R}^n$, this metric coincides with the standard euclidean metric and in particular we have that geodesics are straight lines, that is a geodesic takes the form
$$ c(t) = p + vt.$$
That is, in particular if we consider a unit speed geodesic it has

$$ \frac{d}{dt} c(t) = \frac{q-p}{||q-p||} $$
for some $q$, but then also  (for $t \in [0,1)$ )
$$ \frac{d}{dt} c(t) = \frac{q-c(t)}{||q-c(t)||} = -\operatorname{grad} d(q,\cdot)_{c(t)}. $$

In my intuition, the same should also hold locally for geodesics on an arbitrary Riemannian manifold, that is in a normal neighborhood around some point $p$ , do we have that a geodesic $c(t)$ fulfills

$$ \frac{d}{dt} c(t) = -\operatorname{grad} d(q,\cdot)_{c(t)}?$$

Comment: yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(Riemannian_geometry)

Comment: Yes, because locally the distance is _achieved_ by length of geodesics through $q$. Feel free to answer your own question!

Comment: ...if that geodesic is passing through $q$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I know that and intuitively of course this means that the answer is positive, but to formally show it I would need to do something like $\int_0^1 ||\operatorname{grad} d(q,\cdot)_c(t)|| dt = d(q,p)$, how do I do that? or is there some variational characterization of gradient descent such that it always minimizes path length?

Comment: There's no answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288639/gradient-of-distance-function-corresponding-riemmanian-metric), but the question includes a proof sketch. Does that help? <> Briefly, use Gauss's lemma (as user8268 says) to argue that geodesics' velocities are perpendicular to the tangent planes of geodesic spheres centered at $q$.